# Display WooCommerce Category Description when using Uncode theme

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, taxonomy-terms

Below is the code I have found related to category description display in Uncode theme, but I'm not sure if this is what I should edit or not:

```php
if ($show_title) {
    if ( apply_filters( 'uncode_use_description_in_product_tax_archives', false) ) {
        $get_title = get_queried_object()->description !== '' ? get_queried_object()->description : woocommerce_page_title(false);
    } else {
        $tax = get_taxonomy( get_queried_object()->taxonomy );
        $get_title = single_term_title( '', false); }

    
    $title_content = '<div class="post-title-wrapper"><h1 class="post-title">' . $get_title . '</h1></div>';
}
```

I have tried a few different plugins to try add code snippets. I have tried a few pieces of code which have worked and displayed the description but editing the CSS becomes rather difficult.

Comment: It seems that it is not about category description

Comment: Do you know what would work to show the category description?